# Using sed/awk to retrieve first "non-whitspace token" in each line

Tags: awk, sed, grep, rdf

I have a big file of [N-Triples/N-Quads](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/)
I want to be left with a collection of only subjects.
On smaller files I could have achieved this using:

```
awk '{print $1}' | uniq
```

but `awk` fails for large <s>files</s> **lines**. (several MB).

How can I achieve something similar with `sed`/`grep -o`/etc'...?

EDIT:

awk fails with:

```
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
    FILENAME="file.nq" FNR=308254 NR=308254
```

Comment: How does `awk` fail on large files? Have you tried piping the input in (`awk '{print $1}' < file`)?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes. I accidently wrote large files (it is a large file, but that's not the problem), I should have written long lines. question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[update] Some lines have too many (blank-separated) fields. Try `grep` instead of `awk`:

```
grep -E -o '^[^[:space:]]+' your_input_file | uniq
```

I would advise against using `sed` for this, as it would do a lot of extra-work on each line (to remove the end of the line) on a very big file. Same for `awk`: the line parsing is unnecessary.

Comment: sorry, it's not the file size, I had a (mental) typo, some of the lines are very long... I edited the question

Comment: @giladhoch I have updated my answer

Comment: accepted as it is the fastest working snippet among all other answers. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^ *\([^ ]*\) .*$/\1/g' | uniq
```

This replaces each line with the first sequence of non-spaces.

A faster variant using two `grep`s (to handle lines with leading spaces, as AWK does):

```
grep -o "^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*" | grep -o "[^[:space:]]*" | uniq
```

Comment: works fine, but slower than the `grep` based answer (at least for me).

Comment: Yes, it would be slower; the advantage of this approach is that it matches AWK's behaviour (including on lines which start with spaces).

Comment: luckily, I don't have such lines on my file. but good to know :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Answering the edited question, with `long lines`.

A trick you can use for this case is to use `tr` to interchange spaces and newlines. There are various ways you can get the first record out of the first line. Your problem then becomes one of finding lines which contain a space

```
 { echo # output a newline to get the first record
   cat file
 } | tr ' \n' '\n ' |
   sed -n '/ /s/.* //p'
```

Or

```
 tr ' \n' '\n ' < file | sed -ne '1p' -e '/ /s/.* //p'
```

The idea is that you change

```
this is a long line
and this is another
```

to

```
this
is
a
long
line and
this
is
another
```

so then tools with line length limits don't have problems. If you have tab characters between the fields then you probably want `tr ' \t\n' '\n\n '`

Comment: I don't understand everything you did there, but when I ran it on my file, it only output one line and halted (killed it after a while)

Comment: Oops, fixed program.

Comment: and now it works :-)